# How to restrict usage of specific Drawables in a custom design system?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am implementing a custom design system in Android using Jetpack Compose, and I want to restrict the usage of specific `drawables` to maintain consistency and design integrity. Specifically, I want to restrict the usage of `drawables` to only the **Fluent icons** developed by Microsoft, which are shared as `drawables` in Android Studio.

In my components, I have defined properties that accept icons as `drawables`. However, I want to restrict these properties to only accept Fluent icons, and not allow the users to pass any integers or any other drawables.

How can I achieve this restriction in my custom design system? Should I use annotation processing or implement a custom class that checks for the **Fluent icons**? Or is there a better approach to achieve this?

Any insights or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is only 1 solution to your problem, one approach that i like is using of LocalComposition.

example with spacings

```kotlin
data class Spacing(
    val small: Dp = 8.dp,
    val medium: Dp = 16.dp,
    val large: Dp = 32.dp,
)

val LocalSpacing = compositionLocalOf { Spacing() }

val MaterialTheme.spacing: Spacing
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalSpacing.current


@Composable
fun MainApplicationTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalSpacing provides Spacing(),
    ) {

        MaterialTheme(
            colors = LightColorPalette,
            typography = Typography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

then you wrap in your `MainActivity` your composables with the MainApplicationTheme and you have access to the spacings.

You could do also something like that for your Fluent icons `drawables`

You use the above like that `MaterialTheme.spacing.small`

**Update1**
the code that i was referring that needs some changes from the above snippet is like the following

```kotlin
class Icons

@get:DrawableRes
public val Icons.AddCircle: Int
    get() {
        return R.drawable.add_circle
    }

val LocalIcons = compositionLocalOf { Icons() }

val MaterialTheme.icons: Icons
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalIcons.current

@Composable
fun MainApplicationTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalIcons provides Icons(),
    ) {

        MaterialTheme(
            colors = LightColorPalette,
            typography = Typography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

and use it like this `MaterialTheme.icons.AddCircle`

Comment: I don't think this is feasible with the Drawable Ints

Comment: check the updated snippet, follows up also how it is happening with the `Icons.AddCircle` for compose material icons https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/package-summary